# Обработка исключений

Tags: c++, исключения

Доброго всем времени суток, постепенно осваиваю C++ и наткнулся на тему исключений, стал рыться в интернете, нашел несколько объяснений, которые меня еще больше запутали. Подскажите пожалуйста как правильно в C++ обработывать исключения и приведите пару примеров или скиньте ссылок где есть хорошие незамудренные примеры для понимая,заранее спасибо )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот такой простенький пример для начального понимания:

```
class exception; // класс исключения

try {
    ...
    throw exception(); // [1] генерация исключения exception
    ...
    throw new exception(); // [2] генерация исключения exception*
}
catch(exception e)
{
// Ловим исключение [1]
}
catch(const exception& e)
{
// Ловим исключение [1] (тоже самое, что и предыдущий и рекомендуемый(!!!) способ отлова исключений)
}
catch(exception* p)
{
// Ловим исключение [2]
}
```

Comment: спасибо, если можно скиньте ссылки на реальные примеры для наглядности

Comment: @Егор Соколов примеров под рукой нет, может кто еще поможет или сами поищите в гугле.

Answer (score 1):

главное старайтесь поменьше, а лучше вообще исключить использование так называемого catch evething - перехвата всего

```
catch(...)
{

}
```

это плохой стиль